# What's the difference between using-style and typedef-style?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, typedef, using

```
using IntegerType1 = int;
typedef int IntegerType2;

int main()
{
    IntegerType1 n1 = 1; // OK
    IntegerType2 n2 = 2; // OK
}
```

My questions are:

1. What's the difference between using-style and typedef-style?
2. As we already have typedef-style, what's the motivation to make using-style become a C++ standard?

Comment: There's multiple questions on this already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "using-style" was introduced to allow templated typedefs:

```
template< typename T >
using int_map = std::map< int, T >;
```

You can not do this with `typedef`. I found it strange myself that it was decided to use `using` and not `typedef` as the keyword for this, but I guess the committee must have found some problem with extending the `typedef` syntax.

Comment: With `using` the name of the newly defined type is always on the left side of expression. With `typedef` the name can be in the middle of expression. So `using` improves readability, IMHO.

Comment: @VasilyBiryukov True and I personally like the new `using`-syntax much better than the old `typedef`-syntax. It also has other benefits when you need to apply alignment with [`alignas`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15912208/2073257).

Answer (score 3):

I find that readability is greatly improved even for non-templates:

```
typedef void (*FunctionPtr)();  // right-to-left, identifier in the middle of the definition
using FunctionPtr = void (*)(); // left-to-right, same as variables
```

It's probably minor, but in template-metaprogramming this syntactic advantage makes a program easier to read, and makes template metafunctions easier to refactor towards `constexpr` functions. Essentially replace

```
using T = type_expression;
constexpr auto v = value_expression;
```

Furthermore (appeal to authority), it's also in the [draft Effective C++11/14 guidelines](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.nl/2013/01/effective-c11-content-and-status.html).