# c++ alignas specifier in attribute syntax

Tags: c++

I have been programming in C++ for a long time and decided to learn deeper C++ language. I read a very good site [enter link description here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)
and started reading articles about attributes.

Common syntax attributes give programmers the alignas-specifier with attribute syntax.

How does it work and where I can write attributes with alignas-specifier?

Comment: No. I told about using alignas in attribute syntax.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you're asking. After reading the question linked by @Norrius, what exact questions do you have? Do you have a general question about what it does?

Comment: By link which I added in question you can read.

Comment: Text are next:                                                                                Introduces implementation-defined attributes for types, objects, code, etc.

[[attr]] [[attr1, attr2, attr3(args)]] [[namespace::attr(args)]] alignas_specifier

Comment: You should use `@username` when replying to people not under their own posts, otherwise they might not get a notification and not reply.

Comment: So, can you rephrase the question? As Litty said, it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that the page says that you can use `alignas` inside of `[[ ]]` as well as outside, but that's not the case.

> **alignas**_specifier is a part of the attribute specifier sequence, although it **has different syntax**. It **may appear where the [[...]] attributes appear** and may mix with them (provided it is used where alignas is permitted)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

It doesn't say that you can use `alignas` as an attribute. It says that `alignas` can appear in same locations as attribute lists.

Comment: I understand next that you can write: int x [[deprecated]] alignas(16);

Comment: @KotLeapold What's your question then?

Comment: Can you write some example who you can use alignas specifier in attribute syntax?

Comment: Can you write some example who you can use alignas specifier in attribute syntax?

Comment: @KotLeapold There is only one syntax for it, which is described by [the link mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788947/where-can-i-use-alignas-in-c11). What do you mean by "using it in attribute syntax"?

Comment: I understand correct, I can use alignas in place where I can you any attribute.